# Losing relationships from activerecord model when converting to javascript via reactjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I'm using rails + react via rails-react https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails

Please see my models below:

```
class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tweets
  has_many :scores
end

class Tweet <  ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :interest
  has_many :scores
end

class Score <  ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :interest
  belongs_to :tweet
end
```

These are all working as expected and confirmed in the rails console. Here is where things stop working.

```
<%= react_component('MainComponent', { :tweets => Tweets.all }) %>
```

When the ruby -> javascript conversion happens here none of the tweets in `tweets` contain the `scores` relationship so I can't access them.

```
tweet.scores === undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

I expect this is being caused by the Tweet model being converted to json without the scores association. You can try adding it manually with jbuilder or the `to_json` method.
In your controller (using to_json):

```
@tweetProps = JSON.parse Tweet.all.to_json(include: :scores)
```

and then in the view:

```
<%= react_component('MainComponent', { :tweets => @tweetProps }) %>
```

I know its kind ugly to use `JSON.parse` on `#to_json` but see if this works. If it does, you'll probably be able to refactor with a `find_by_sql` subquery or maybe even just using `Tweet.includes(:scores)` instead of `Tweet.all`.

Comment: Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: you can make a custom `to_h` for tweet to be able to include scores